# Visual Studio Server Explorer organization of stored procedures and functions

Tags: visual-studio-2010, function, stored-procedures, organizer

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 and have created MANY functions and stored procedures. VS naturally has folders for Stored Procedures and Functions and that is helpful. However, I have  about 50 functions which are all in one big pile albeit sorted alphabetically.

Does anyone know of a way to create sub-folders to help me organize my functions? It would sure help finding the one I need quickly.

To clarify, I am not asking for help in organizing my Solution Explorer. I would like to better organize my Server Explorer.

Thanks in advance,
Rob

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Server Management Studio does not allow you to create your own folders - you have to use its pre-defined folder structure. However, you can apply a temporary filter to a folder which should help you find objects quicker. Right click on the folder and select Filter.

Alternatively, you could create your own schemas and organise your functions within these - ie you would have [schema_name].[function_name] rather than [dbo].[function_name].